# Can my iron neurons work like a biological quantum computer?

Tags: brain

I decided to describe the evolution of scientifically plausible alien creatures and thought about it and decided to make sure that their neurons contained a large amount of elemental iron, which should have a major role in the work of the neurons of my aliens. So each iron molecule inside their neurons will be able to function as an eight-polar magnet, which, after the formation of peculiar magnetic cells, will self-assemble and form cell-like shells, the surfaces of which will act as biochemical switches and other components of the circuit, forming complex memory arrays. Each of these magnetic shells will contain a number of [RMO12O⁴⁰(VO)2]q-ions, which, when stimulated by bioelectricity, will function as two-qubit valves. This is followed by self-assembly into arrays of gate elements and each brain cell will function as a nanoprocessor, using internal arrays for data processing and an external shell for storing memory, connections with other cells and as a connection for bioelectric energy and nerve inputs as a result, in general terms representing a biological quantum computer. However, is the existence and operation of this system possible?

Comment: There is no such thing as an iron "molecule", unless you mean an isolated iron atom; which cannot be, because isolated iron atoms can exist only as a high tempeature gas. You probably mean an iron crystal, but the rest of the technobabble is way over my head. I have no idea what a left bracket arr emm ow twelve ow to-the-fortieth left parenthesis vee ow right parenthesis two right bracket queue dash ion is or might be. However, if you have a workable idea for a quantum processor operating at room temperature you should patent it *immediately*.

Comment: I adhere to information communism — if you have sent information to the public, then it belongs to everyone.

Comment: Are you asking about the real world, or are you asking about a fictional world that you're building? You're question is too far out there to be the former and since you can decide what is and isn't possible in the latter I'm not sure why you're asking us about it.

Answer (score 4):

### Heck no.

First of all, "scientifically plausible" means the creatures must be capable of *evolving* in the way you describe. As far as we understand evolution — what you're describing is evolutionarily impossible and therefore scientifically impossible.

Second, you appear to believe that the presence of a computer means (metaphorically) you can immediately play video games on it. *That isn't true.* Computers must be programmed<sup>1</sup> and programming meets the expected use of the machines, so unless you're anticipating God programming your creatures, even if it were scientifically plausible to have magnetic-core memories and quantum valves for brains, they'd just sit there and die because there's no software making the computer do anything useful.

*I strongly suggest you take more time to understand how biological brains work.* Not that humans have a great understanding of how brains work. It's a beginning, but we're still a long way away from duplicating an entire brain on a macro-level, much less the micro-level required to be a living creature's brain.

I'd like to point out something else. Your two questions suggest you don't understand how elegant and amazing biology is compared to human-crafted synthetics like batteries and computers. For what it's intended to do, the human brain is *breathtaking* in its abilities and construction. While it's theoretically possible that humans will eventually create what Star Trek described as a "positronic brain," that creation will ***never*** be evolutionarily or biologically possible. I'm not even a biologist and I'm 100% certain that claim won't be disputed in the lifetime of anyone living on the planet today—or the lifetime of their great-great-granchildren.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Perhaps you've heard the phrase, "garbage-in, garbage-out?" Computers are only as smart as the people who program them, which is why software is constantly full of bugs, short-sighted assumptions about the UX, and in need of constant upgrading. Evolution solved these problems over the course of millions of years such that the result are fauna capable of living life without external programming<sup>2</sup> — and yet it STILL occasionally results in defects great and small. The idea of using an actual computing matrix in place of a brain is a science-fiction staple — but unless you're talking about a synthetic creature cloned to order, it isn't scientifically plausible.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *And just in case someone's prone to argue the point, "external programming" means "you need to explain to it how to get the heart to pump," not "you need to show it how to use a hammer" or "you need to show it how to hunt food." Don't strain too hard at a gnat when the question is about a creature that actually needs the BIOS to be installed.*</sub>

Comment: why can't these organisms evolve?

Comment: Frank, if you don't know the answer to that question, then it's impossible for you to create scientifically plausible creatures. I'm afraid I don't have the time to give you eight years of education to help you understand the limitation. The only explanation I can think of short enough for a comment is this: evolution is reactive to external stimuli and there is no external stimuli that would cause magnetic-core memory to evolve.

Answer (score 1):

In your world building, not everything has to be plausible. With quantum computing not everything in the real world is plausible either. You have a lot of text that describes at the higher levels of how your biological quantum computer would work and however you want to break that out is probably fine.

For your quantum computer to work and be scalable in the real world - around 2000 a guy came up with what are now called the [DiVincenzo's criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiVincenzo%27s_criteria).
To paraphrase:

1. A scalable physical system with well-characterized qubit
2. The ability to initialize the state of the qubits to a simple fiducial state
3. Long relevant decoherence times
4. A "universal" set of quantum gates
5. A qubit-specific measurement capability
6. The ability to interconvert stationary and flying qubits
7. The ability to faithfully transmit flying qubits between specified locations

So for your question:

Q. What is your q-bit?:

A. Some type of iron containing molecule that has has at least two energy levels where an electron, or spin, or some other quantity can exist for a long time without somehow mixing its state with the environment. Since you are talking about magnetism - it is probably an electron spin, or an set of electrons in some sort of atom or molecule that are all spinning in the same way when they are programmed in some way.

Q. How do you program the initial state of the q-bit.

A. Well, the details matter. Using 'spintronics' your can polarize the spin of electrons by sending the electrons through a thin layer of a ferromagnetic material for example making a spin field effect transistor, but since your alien evolved, I am choosing to assume that your q-bit molecules are in some kind of squishy biological matrix and little filamentary antennas structures in the brain are sending out short range RF pulses that set the q-bit spinning such that are spinning in the right energy level. The problem with this is that if the energy levels are closely spaced, I might have to have the creature operate at cryogenic temperatures, so maybe back to a spin FET like structure where little pulses of current might set up the spins the correct way.... or maybe something else.

Q. Long relevant decoherence times -

A. This and how fast you can program the gates is important tradeoff on how well you computer scales. If your molecule has closely spaced energy levels - thermal energy will make it unusable at higher temperatures, but maybe your molecule for some reason has widely spaced energy levels and is protected from interactions somehow so the state is maintained for some long (microseconds or milliseconds instead of femtoseconds or picoseconds) amount of time. The the problem becomes how do you program the molecule to be in the right state, and then have it interact or be coupled to another q-bit in a useful way.

Etc. Etc.  the universal quantum gate, how information goes from the onely location to the other location are more related to the architecture of the quantum computer and details of how you would program it.  For your biologically evolved alien, it may not understand how its brain works. (I don't think we humans necessarily understand how our brains work either).

So it is up to you as to what is plausible or not. But in quantum computing thinking about storage and algorithms can be quite a bit different than how we think about regular computers. BTW, there are non quantum computers like neuromorphic computers that are weird too. Ideas like registers, RAM, clocks and timing, can be a differentin these other types of computers. So a nanoprocesser is fine, but what does it mean? It is hard to tell.